# ASP.NET MVC partial views rendering

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, partial-views, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I'm a beginner in ASP.NET MVC and I want to have a website like this :

- A main page that load all the css/js files, subscribe to JavaScript events, store JavaScript variables
- Partial views that replace the page content without reloading it, and keep the JavaScript variables,etc...

What is the best way to to it ?

I tried :

```
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")',
            data: { cardid: currentCardId },
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (data) {
                SetData(data);
            }
        });

function SetData(data) {
    alert(data);
    $("#divPartialView").html(data);
}
```

In my HomeController, I return a PartialView();

(It doesn't work yet but it should)

Is there a simple/better way ?

I also tried this but it doesn't work :

```
$('#divPartialView').load(@Html.Action("Index", "Home")));
```

Also, Can I define the Model in the PartialView ?

Comment: Your first example should work, and is the best method IMO. Have you checked the console for errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your example should work

This is a working example

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")',
      data: { id: $('#mycomponent').attr('data-id')},
      success: function (data2) {
                    $('#mydiv').html(data2);
               },
      error: function (a, b, c) {
            alert(a);
      }
});
```

my controller

```
public ActionResult ActionName(int id)
        {
            return PartialView("mypartialViewPath",id);
        }
```

partial view

```
@model int
<div>
...content
</div>
```

Comment: Ok it seems to work, but I have a bool variable in my JavaScript. If I do an alert of the variable before "$("#divPartialView").html(data);", it displays "true". but after, when I do the alert from the partial view, it displays "false... Do you have an idea why ?

Comment: @Gab which is the variable? can I see the code? remember that the variable exist only in the success context

Comment: I have a layout file. In the layout, I initialize the variable : "var myVariable = false", and in a div, I have "@RenderBody()" Then I have my main View that use this layout. I set the variable to true, then I call the ajax function and alert the variable from my partial view. It's like if the page was reloaded... If I initialize the variable directly in my main View and not in the layout, it works